# Publish to Url the old way VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, one-click-web-publishing

Anyone know if you can simply publish to a url?  I don't know what the heck the new publish to web is but I don't like it.  I want to be able to just publish to a url like I was able to in VS 2008 and down.  I don't have a service endpoint to give it so not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the server you are publishing to has to support IIS FrontPageServerExtensions. or are you trying to publish to an FTP url? `ftp://msdn.com/` for example

Reference http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/winformssetup/thread/fa09fa69-e0b4-4970-981e-69175c5764ea

Then the newest option is Web Deploy packages

where your service endpoint would be

```
https://HostingCompanyURL:8172/msdeploy.axd (for example, https://contoso.com:8172/msdeploy.axd)
```

- from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337.aspx